# How do you use inst.text in Qubes?

Tags: qubes

> X startup failed, aborting installation
>
> If the graphical installation interface fails to start, try again with the inst.text bootoption to start text installation

Where or how do I set the `inst.text` option?

Answer (score 1):

use `--inst.text` after initrd.img